# What are the reasons for not hosting a compiler on a live server?

Tags: python, deployment, compiler-construction, pip, binaries

Where I currently work we've had a small debate about deploying our Python code to the production servers. I voted to build binary dependencies (like the python mysql drivers) on the server itself, just using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This was quickly vetoed with no better explanation that "we don't put compilers on the live servers". As a result our deployment process is becoming convoluted and over-engineered simply to avoid this compilation step.

My question is this: What's the reason these days to avoid having a compiler on live servers?

Comment: Aren't you going to need to install those dependencies to run in production anyway?

Comment: @DeaconDesperado, yep, but they don't need to be built on the box they will ultimately reside.

Comment: I know PIP builds them after downloading the packages, but I've never heard this dismissed out of hand as a 'deal-breaker' for deployment environments, especially since it only needs to be done once.  The pip freeze combined with fabric and virtualenv is pretty much the only deployment methodology I've ever been familiar with.  I'm with you Phil, sounds like needless overcomplication to me, at least in the case of PIP and python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the prevailing wisdom on servers installs is that they should be as stripped-down as possible. There are a few motivations for this, but they don't really apply all that directly to your question about a compiler:

- **Minimize resource usage.** GCC might take up a little extra disk space, but probably not enough to matter - and it won't be running most of the time, so CPU/memory usage isn't a big concern.
- **Minimize complexity**. Building on your server might add a few more failure modes to your build process (if you build elsewhere, then at least you will notice something wrong *before* you go mess with your production server), but otherwise, it won't get in the way.
- **Minimize [attack surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_surface)**. As others have pointed out, by the time an attacker can make use of a compiler, you're probably already screwed..

At my company, we generally don't care too much if compilers are installed on our servers, but we also *never* run `pip` on our servers, for a rather different reason. We're not so concerned about where packages are built, but when and how they are downloaded.

The particularly paranoid among us will take note that pip (and easy_install) will happily install packages from PYPI without any form of authentication (no SSL, no package signatures, ...). Further, many of these aren't actually hosted on PYPI; pip and easy_install follow redirects. So, there are two problems here:

- If pypi - or any of the other sites on which your dependencies are hosted - goes down, then your build process will fail
- If an attacker somehow manages to perform a man-in-the-middle attack against your server as it's attempting to download a dependency package, then he'll be able to insert malicious code into the download

So, we download packages when we first add a dependency, do our best to make sure the source is genuine (this is not foolproof), and add them into our own version-control system. We do actually build our packages on a separate build server, but this is less crucial; we simply find it useful to have a binary package we can quickly deploy to multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to refer to this [serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/143364/remote-server-security-handling-compiler-tools).

It makes sense to avoid exploits being compiled remotely

It makes sense also to me that in terms of security, it will only make the task harder for a hijacker without than with a compiler, but it's not perfect.

Comment: If someone has access to run arbitrary commands on your system, you're already screwed. (as the linked post says)

Answer (score 0):

It would put a heavy strain on the server?

Comment: Occasionally compiling a few things shouldn't produce much load.

Comment: A good point for a CPU intensive system but these are simple app servers and in this case the overhead is negligible.

Comment: @MrD True, but I haven't come across any Python packages with huge effort in compiling.